# Loading Stack Exchange sites (cdn.sstatic.net)

Tags: support, cdn

I'm having some issues loading the Stack Exchange network sites. Meta Stack Overflow is the only one that works for me, and all the other ones hang up during page loading with the message "Waiting for cdn.sstatic.net".

What could be causing this?

---

Following the template provided on other questions related to this,

1. Sample CSS file that is giving me trouble: http://cdn.sstatic.net/rpg/all.css?v=c9c55a2b82c5
2. My [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address): 66.191.248.79
3. [First tracert http://www.ethland.com/tracert1.png](http://www.ethland.com/tracert1.png)
4. [Second tracert http://www.ethland.com/tracert2.png](http://www.ethland.com/tracert2.png)
5. NetDNA Atlanta Datacenter

Comment: No Repro. Even in InCognito/InPrivate.

Comment: I don't expect people to be able to reproduce my issue, but I just have no idea how to diagnose the source of the problem.

Comment: status-norepro here.

Comment: +1 issue exists. It seems to be quite ugly bug, hard to find.

Comment: What is the actual argument to *tracert* in 3. and 4.?

Comment: Yeah, strangely meta gets that file (I assume) locally: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/all.css...`, and using Firebug or what-have-you do slip in that css file in lieu of the  `cdn.sstatic.net` link makes SO look like Meta. ;^) I'm having the same issue with a proxy.

Comment: Fwiw, using `//meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackoverflow/all.css` in place of the cdn link fixes it. So if something like [Redirector for Firefox](https://github.com/einaregilsson/Redirector) still worked, you'd have a workaround.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, from more than a month now. Using the same laptop, both at work and home, both with chrome / firefox / opera, i get 409 for resources in cdn.sstatic.net. Using a random open proxy only for that domain works

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the cache and cookies and retry opening the site. Also please check that proxy is applied to your browser or not.

If yes, then remove that proxy and try again. Hope this will help. Please let us know in case of any other issues.